# In SQL how can I get only the first result per group

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table that looks like the following:

| Material | Branch | PRICE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| A | B1 | 19.00 |
| A | B2 | 17.00 |
| A | B3 | 17.00 |
| B | B1 | 20.00 |
| B | B2 | 22.00 |
| B | B3 | 19.00 |
| C | B4 | 22.00 |
| C | C3 | 19.00 |

And I'm trying to write a query that will return me only the first result in the list with the highest price.  So for example what I would want return from my query is:

A     B1   19.00

B     B2   22.00

C     B4   22.00

In case any values match i still only want the first result in the list.  i am using MSSQL to write this query, can anyone help me?  I have tried using row_number with a partition but am not seeing the results I am expecting.

Answer (score -1):

With row number, this would be:

```
select t.*
from (select t.*,
             row_number() over (partition by material order by price desc) as seqnum
      from t
     ) t
where seqnum = 1;
```